# Using date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC') in PHPMailer

Tags: php, timezone, smtp, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer in my project and I want to deploy it into an domain that I own for tests.

I found an example using SMTP in GitHub, and I'm using it on the project (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps). It works fine but I'm not quite sure if I should include the following line in my code:

```
<?php
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
?>
```

I'm pretty sure my default timezone is set on the server, and I would like to know if setting it again could cause any problem or side effects in my code.

note: I work with php DateTime class in my project but every time I create a new instance of it, I specify its DateTimeZone.
Cheers !

Comment: A _default_ is a default, no matter how many times you set it.

Comment: So it would be perfectly fine just to hang on to the default timezone I already have - even if it's different from 'Etc/UTC'. is that it?

Comment: It's possible for PHP to be configured *without* a default timezone at all, which is where it can run into problems. This has been around for a while, and it may have been fixed in more recent PHP versions, but the advice still stands.